# Visual Studio 2015 not linking static libraries from C++/CLI projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

I work on a large system (10+ EXEs and 50+ DLLs).  The entirety of this system was written in C++ up until around 2005, when we began migrating components to the .NET framework.

It would help our migration efforts tremendously if I could switch individual DLL projects to C++/CLI and provide both a legacy unmanaged API and a new managed API into the same DLL.

This approach worked when we first started, but then broke soon after.  Visual Studio does not appear to support two C++/CLI projects linking to each other via the unmanaged API.

Is there any way to get this to work beyond the brute-force approach of adding export libraries from one project as content to another?  That's what project dependencies are supposed to handle already.

Comment: Right, linking *managed* code in a static library is not possible.  The linker cannot do job that the CLR is supposed to do, managed code is bound at runtime.  You'll get into this kind of trouble when you compile native code with /clr in effect.  That works too well but begets the worst of both worlds.  Partitioning the code better is the workaround, keep native code in static libraries and managed code in assemblies.

Comment: @Hans this looks like a build system question where the toolchain handles it just fine

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps `#pragma comment` in the native header files would be useful.  For that to work you need each project configured to write its generated import library into a common area that can be added to the library search path, but it saves you from having to manually add lib files as linker inputs, or as project content items.  Also, it makes keeping release and debug library versions separate more easily, since you can just have a different search path for each configuration, instead of having to add each individual library twice to every single consuming project.